# Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, persistence, spring-transactions

I have a problem when I want to save a "TablasMaestra" entity that contains a OneToMany relationship of "DatosMaestro" entities. I create the object MasterTables and insert a list of new "MasterData" entities.

All "DatosMaestro" objects have the id null because they are new objects.

When I call the saveTablasMaestra method it is when me
returns the exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.soprasteria.mater.entity.DatosMaestro#com.soprasteria.mater.entity.DatosMaestroPK@3fd1]
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:164)
```

I attach the code of the entities and services.

```
package com.soprasteria.mater.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;


/**
 * The persistent class for the tablas_maestras database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="tablas_maestras")
@NamedQuery(name="TablasMaestra.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TablasMaestra t")
public class TablasMaestra implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="descripcion_castellano", length=255)
    private String descripcionCastellano;

    @Column(name="descripcion_catalan", length=255)
    private String descripcionCatalan;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_baja")
    private Date fechaBaja;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_creacion")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_modificacion")
    private Date fechaModificacion;

    @Column(name="usuario_baja", length=45)
    private String usuarioBaja;

    @Column(name="usuario_creacion", length=45)
    private String usuarioCreacion;

    @Column(name="usuario_modificacion", length=45)
    private String usuarioModificacion;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to DatosMaestro
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="tablasMaestra", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DatosMaestro> datosMaestros;

    public TablasMaestra() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcionCastellano() {
        return this.descripcionCastellano;
    }

    public void setDescripcionCastellano(String descripcionCastellano) {
        this.descripcionCastellano = descripcionCastellano;
    }

    public String getDescripcionCatalan() {
        return this.descripcionCatalan;
    }

    public void setDescripcionCatalan(String descripcionCatalan) {
        this.descripcionCatalan = descripcionCatalan;
    }

    public Date getFechaBaja() {
        return this.fechaBaja;
    }

    public void setFechaBaja(Date fechaBaja) {
        this.fechaBaja = fechaBaja;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return this.fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getFechaModificacion() {
        return this.fechaModificacion;
    }

    public void setFechaModificacion(Date fechaModificacion) {
        this.fechaModificacion = fechaModificacion;
    }

    public String getUsuarioBaja() {
        return this.usuarioBaja;
    }

    public void setUsuarioBaja(String usuarioBaja) {
        this.usuarioBaja = usuarioBaja;
    }

    public String getUsuarioCreacion() {
        return this.usuarioCreacion;
    }

    public void setUsuarioCreacion(String usuarioCreacion) {
        this.usuarioCreacion = usuarioCreacion;
    }

    public String getUsuarioModificacion() {
        return this.usuarioModificacion;
    }

    public void setUsuarioModificacion(String usuarioModificacion) {
        this.usuarioModificacion = usuarioModificacion;
    }

    public List<DatosMaestro> getDatosMaestros() {
        return this.datosMaestros;
    }

    public void setDatosMaestros(List<DatosMaestro> datosMaestros) {
        this.datosMaestros = datosMaestros;
    }

    public DatosMaestro addDatosMaestro(DatosMaestro datosMaestro) {
        getDatosMaestros().add(datosMaestro);
        datosMaestro.setTablasMaestra(this);

        return datosMaestro;
    }

    public DatosMaestro removeDatosMaestro(DatosMaestro datosMaestro) {
        getDatosMaestros().remove(datosMaestro);
        datosMaestro.setTablasMaestra(null);

        return datosMaestro;
    }


   @PrePersist
   private void prePersiste() {
       for(DatosMaestro datosMaestro:this.datosMaestros) {
           if(datosMaestro.getId()==null) {
               datosMaestro.setId(new DatosMaestroPK());
           }
           datosMaestro.setTablasMaestra(this);
       }
   }


}
```

```
    private void cargaDatosMaestro(String tabla) {
        TablasMaestraDTO tablaMaestra = new TablasMaestraDTO();
        tablaMaestra.setDescripcionCastellano(tabla);
        tablaMaestra.setDescripcionCatalan(tabla);

        List<DatoMaestroDTO> listDatoMaestro= new ArrayList<DatoMaestroDTO>();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            DatoMaestroDTO datoMaestro = new DatoMaestroDTO();
            datoMaestro.setDescripcionCastellano(tabla+i);
            datoMaestro.setDescripcionCatalan(tabla+ i +" cat");
            datoMaestro.setTablaMaestra(tablaMaestra);
            listDatoMaestro.add(datoMaestro);
        }
        tablaMaestra.setDatosMaestros(listDatoMaestro);

        tablaMaestra=insertTablaMaestra(tablaMaestra);




    }


    private TablasMaestraDTO insertTablaMaestra(TablasMaestraDTO tablaMaestra) {
        tablaMaestra.setFechaCreacion(new Date());
        tablaMaestra=tablasMaestraService.saveTablasMaestra(tablaMaestra);
        return tablaMaestra;
    }
```

```
/**
     * Graba en base de datos la entidad TablasMaestra
     * 
     * @param TablasMaestraDTO
     * @return TablasMaestraDTO
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public TablasMaestraDTO saveTablasMaestra(TablasMaestraDTO dto) {
        TablasMaestra entity = new ModelMapper().map(dto, TablasMaestra.class);
        entity=tablasMaestrasRepository.save(entity);
        if (entity != null) {
            dto = new ModelMapper().map(entity, TablasMaestraDTO.class);
        }
        return dto;
    }
```

```
package com.soprasteria.mater.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The primary key class for the datos_maestros database table.
 * 
 */
@Embeddable
public class DatosMaestroPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="id", unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id_pk;

    @Column(name="tablas_maestras_id_tabla", insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int tablasMaestrasIdTabla;

    public DatosMaestroPK() {
    }
    public int getId_pk() {
        return this.id_pk;
    }
    public void setId_pk(int id_pk) {
        this.id_pk = id_pk;
    }
    public int getTablasMaestrasIdTabla() {
        return this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla;
    }
    public void setTablasMaestrasIdTabla(int tablasMaestrasIdTabla) {
        this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla = tablasMaestrasIdTabla;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof DatosMaestroPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        DatosMaestroPK castOther = (DatosMaestroPK)other;
        return 
            (this.id_pk == castOther.id_pk)
            && (this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla == castOther.tablasMaestrasIdTabla);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.id_pk;
        hash = hash * prime + this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla;

        return hash;
    }
}
```

```
package com.soprasteria.mater.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import com.soprasteria.mater.entity.DatosMaestro;
import com.soprasteria.mater.entity.TablasMaestra;

public interface TablasMaestrasRepository extends CrudRepository<TablasMaestra, Integer>{
      @Query(value = "select count(*) from TablasMaestra tablasMaestra where tablasMaestra.id = ?1")
      long subtaskNumber(int datosMaestroId);

      @Query(value = "select max(tablasMaestra.id) from TablasMaestra tablasMaestra")
      long lastDatosMaestroId();

      @Query(value="select tablasMaestra from TablasMaestra tablasMaestra order by id desc")
      public List<DatosMaestro> findAllByOrderByCreatedOnDesc();
}
```

Comment: This can happen when you have used same session object for read & write Or if you are putting same object in single session. They are referring to the same row in the database (i.e. the same primary key) but they're different copies of it.
Try perhaps:
@ManyToOne(cascade = {PERSIST, MERGE})

Comment: Or change to @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)

Comment: I've put the 2 changes and it gives the same mistake

Comment: Curios that GenerationType.Sequence is not working :(  One Option more is to save DatosMaestroPK before saving TablasMaestra :)

Comment: The autoincremental sequence is in the database.
I would not be able to put the pk before saving because I do not have the numbers before persisting.
I don't know if using CrudRepository will have anything to do with this

Comment: U can try to change to JpaRepository? But i think thats not the problem. Perhaps the lack of  Equals and Hash method in TablasMaestra returns different values for different entities??

Comment: The equals and hash method is in the DatosMaestroPK that is inside DatosMaestro. 
Should I also be in TablasMaestra?

Comment: What's the point of the following code? `if(datosMaestro.getId()==null) { datosMaestro.setId(new DatosMaestroPK()); }`? Does it work when you remove it? Also, where is the value for `DatosMaestroPK.id_pk` supposed to come from? There's no `@GeneratedValue` declared. It would be easier if you posted the `DatosMaestro` as well. The problem is likely that you're trying to save a bunch of `DatosMaestro` entities, each having the same PK

Comment: BTW Why do you feel you need `@NamedQuery(name="TablasMaestra.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM TablasMaestra t")`? `CrudRepository` already has a `findAll` method

Comment: I have changed the methods as indicated in the comment below for trying other things. But it makes another mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes to try different ways of doing the transaction. I pass the code to you as I have it now, surely I will have unnecessary things because of the tests I am doing. Any suggestion for improvement will be welcome. Thank you very much!

```
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void cargaDatosMaestro(String tabla) {
        TablasMaestraDTO tablaMaestra = new TablasMaestraDTO();
        tablaMaestra.setDescripcionCastellano(tabla);
        tablaMaestra.setDescripcionCatalan(tabla);
        tablaMaestra=insertTablaMaestra(tablaMaestra);
        List<AreaDTO> areas = areaService.getAreas();
        for(int i=0;i<4;i++) {
            DatoMaestroDTO datoMaestro = new DatoMaestroDTO();
            datoMaestro.setDescripcionCastellano(tabla+i);
            datoMaestro.setDescripcionCatalan(tabla+ i +" cat");
            datoMaestro.setTablaMaestra(tablaMaestra);
            datoMaestro.setArea(areas.get(0));
            datoMaestroService.saveDatoMaestro(datoMaestro);;
        }

    }
```

```
    /**
     * Graba en base de datos la entidad DatoMaestro
     * 
     * @param DatoMaestroDTO
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public void saveDatoMaestro(DatoMaestroDTO dto) {
        DatosMaestro entity = new ModelMapper().map(dto, DatosMaestro.class);
//      TablasMaestra tablaTemp = null;
//      if(entity.getTablasMaestra()!=null) {
//          tablaTemp=entity.getTablasMaestra();
//          entity.setTablasMaestra(null);
//      }
        entity=datomaestroRepository.save(entity);
//      entity.setTablasMaestra(tablaTemp);
    }
```

```
package com.soprasteria.mater.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;


/**
 * The persistent class for the datos_maestros database table.
 * 
 */
@Entity
@Table(name="datos_maestros")
@NamedQuery(name="DatosMaestro.findAll", query="SELECT d FROM DatosMaestro d")
public class DatosMaestro implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private DatosMaestroPK id;

    @Column(name="descripcion_castellano", length=255)
    private String descripcionCastellano;

    @Column(name="descripcion_catalan", length=255)
    private String descripcionCatalan;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_baja")
    private Date fechaBaja;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_creacion")
    private Date fechaCreacion;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name="fecha_modificacion")
    private Date fechaModificacion;

    private int orden;

    @Column(name="usuario_baja", length=45)
    private String usuarioBaja;

    @Column(name="usuario_creacion", length=45)
    private String usuarioCreacion;

    @Column(name="usuario_modificacion", length=45)
    private String usuarioModificacion;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Area
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="area_id_area", nullable=false)
    private Area area;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to TablasMaestra
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade= CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="tablas_maestras_id_tabla", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private TablasMaestra tablasMaestra;

    public DatosMaestro() {
    }

    public DatosMaestroPK getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(DatosMaestroPK id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescripcionCastellano() {
        return this.descripcionCastellano;
    }

    public void setDescripcionCastellano(String descripcionCastellano) {
        this.descripcionCastellano = descripcionCastellano;
    }

    public String getDescripcionCatalan() {
        return this.descripcionCatalan;
    }

    public void setDescripcionCatalan(String descripcionCatalan) {
        this.descripcionCatalan = descripcionCatalan;
    }

    public Date getFechaBaja() {
        return this.fechaBaja;
    }

    public void setFechaBaja(Date fechaBaja) {
        this.fechaBaja = fechaBaja;
    }

    public Date getFechaCreacion() {
        return this.fechaCreacion;
    }

    public void setFechaCreacion(Date fechaCreacion) {
        this.fechaCreacion = fechaCreacion;
    }

    public Date getFechaModificacion() {
        return this.fechaModificacion;
    }

    public void setFechaModificacion(Date fechaModificacion) {
        this.fechaModificacion = fechaModificacion;
    }

    public int getOrden() {
        return this.orden;
    }

    public void setOrden(int orden) {
        this.orden = orden;
    }

    public String getUsuarioBaja() {
        return this.usuarioBaja;
    }

    public void setUsuarioBaja(String usuarioBaja) {
        this.usuarioBaja = usuarioBaja;
    }

    public String getUsuarioCreacion() {
        return this.usuarioCreacion;
    }

    public void setUsuarioCreacion(String usuarioCreacion) {
        this.usuarioCreacion = usuarioCreacion;
    }

    public String getUsuarioModificacion() {
        return this.usuarioModificacion;
    }

    public void setUsuarioModificacion(String usuarioModificacion) {
        this.usuarioModificacion = usuarioModificacion;
    }

    public Area getArea() {
        return this.area;
    }

    public void setArea(Area area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public TablasMaestra getTablasMaestra() {
        return this.tablasMaestra;
    }

    public void setTablasMaestra(TablasMaestra tablasMaestra) {
        this.tablasMaestra = tablasMaestra;
    }

   @PrePersist
   private void prePersiste() {
       if (getId() == null) {
           setId(new DatosMaestroPK());
       }
       if(getTablasMaestra()!=null) {
           getId().setTablasMaestrasIdTabla(getTablasMaestra().getId());
       }
   }

}
```

```
package com.soprasteria.mater.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

/**
 * The primary key class for the datos_maestros database table.
 * 
 */
@Embeddable
public class DatosMaestroPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="tablas_maestras_id_tabla")
    private int tablasMaestrasIdTabla;

    public DatosMaestroPK() {
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getTablasMaestrasIdTabla() {
        return this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla;
    }
    public void setTablasMaestrasIdTabla(int tablasMaestrasIdTabla) {
        this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla = tablasMaestrasIdTabla;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(other instanceof DatosMaestroPK)) {
            return false;
        }
        DatosMaestroPK castOther = (DatosMaestroPK)other;
        return 
            (this.id == castOther.id)
            && (this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla == castOther.tablasMaestrasIdTabla);
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * prime + this.id;
        hash = hash * prime + this.tablasMaestrasIdTabla;

        return hash;
    }
}
```

This is the exception that is released now:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.soprasteria.mater.entity.TablasMaestra; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.soprasteria.mater.entity.TablasMaestra
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy122.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.service.DatoMaestroService.saveDatoMaestro(DatoMaestroService.java:63)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.service.DatoMaestroService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$60d4a08a.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:749)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.service.DatoMaestroService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f07d9a5f.saveDatoMaestro(<generated>)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.CargaInicialTestService.cargaDatosMaestro(CargaInicialTestService.java:100)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.CargaInicialTestService.cargaInicialBDD(CargaInicialTestService.java:57)
    at com.soprasteria.mater.MaterApplicationTests.cargaInicial(MaterApplicationTests.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.soprasteria.mater.entity.TablasMaestra
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:806)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:773)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:467)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:414)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:252)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:782)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:767)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:304)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy112.persist(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:490)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:377)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:629)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:593)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139)
    ... 53 more
```